# Evaluation of primefaces for Java web application

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf, mobile-website, primefaces

I am currently working on making Java web application using JSF (Java Server Faces) technology with PrimeFaces framework. And it is my first time I work on java web applications since PHP and .Net.

My requirements are: 
- framework should support Tomacat 6+ server and Weblogic 10+ 
- framework should be compatible with IE 7+ and Firefox 3+ browsers. 
- framework should provide support for mobile browsers in IOS (iPhone) and Android. Since I need to make mobile version of this application.

So My Question:

Is PrimeFaces is suitable for this kind of web application? 
Are there any other frameworks that are better alternative ?

Thanks in advance and I appreciate any comments..

Answer (score 2):

No JSF frameworks come to mind that support the entire list that you have provided.

Full support for iPhone AND Android AND all major PC web browsers?

[Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/) supports major PC web browsers and CAN be run on Tomcat 6 with a little bit of love.

For mobile web development look at [Touchfaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/touch/index.jsf).

Comment: thanks maple_shaft for reply... I know it is little too much requirements but I am still looking for something to use for my java web application. I may ask again can I survive in the project using primefaces or i will stuck in the middle of project??

Comment: I have no trouble using PrimeFaces with Tomcat 6. The only thing I can think that `little bit of love` would mean is the context.xml configuration needed if your using `<p:push>` ?

Comment: TouchFaces is deprecated in favor of PrimeFaces Mobile which supports iOS and Android.http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/mobile/index.jsf